# Using neural networks to recognize digits in a scene

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, mnist

Neural nets are widely used (as example for the MNIST dataset). Using neural networks and convolutional neural networks, in particular, we can get over 99% accuracy. However, the MNIST dataset is a dataset where each image only has one digit cropped and centered so that it is always in the same position.

If I were to create a neural network to recognize digits where the digits may not be in the center (and possibly there may be other objects or digits in the scene), how do I go about developing it?

I need to detect the digits and their position.

Comment: These problems are called _scene text detection_ and, more generally, _object localization_. A modern solution is to use [Spatial Transformer Networks](http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/07/spatial_transformers.html). [pytorch 0.2 now makes this easier](https://github.com/YongyiTang92/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/05-mytest/STN_test.ipynb).

Comment: this reminded me of google street view house number recognition: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/